# iOS x.x adoption rate

Tags: ios

I'm curious what percent of iOS users are running with version of the operating system. I'd really like to cut my new app as 6.0+ but also don't want to screw over the 5.x folk.

I did a lot of Googling, but it mainly turns up tech articles, that either aren't current or not informative enough (all about iOS 6.1).

Is there a known source for this that is updated in real(ish) time? I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 4):

I have data for several apps, totalling more than a million downloads, with I can combine and disclose as long as I'm suitably non-specific.

From our numbers it looks like the current user breakdown in the US, Canada and Europe is approximately:

- iOS 6.0.x — 76%
- iOS 5.1.x — 17%
- iOS 4.x — 4%
- iOS 5.0.x — 2%

Worldwide — which in terms of our users mostly means adding Latin America, so this is all of the Americas and Europe — that looks more like:

- iOS 6.0.x — 44%
- iOS 5.1.x — 43%
- iOS 4.x — 8%
- iOS 5.0.x — 4%

With negligible numbers on 6.1 so far but I think our aggregation probably has a slight delay to it.

That said, the two sets of numbers aren't exactly like for like. All products are similar but those contributing to the top set of numbers are much more popular than the others.

If I had to speculate I'd say it's not unreasonable that more popular apps should see a more lopsided curve because they're more likely to be tried out by people just browsing the store, and people who have bought hardware recently are more likely to browse the store. But that's just off-the-cuff speculation which I've no statistical basis for whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Adoption rates for each update will change over time, obviously, but, at time of writing, here's some data from Onswipe (dated Jan 30th 2013),

http://techcrunch.com/2013/01/30/ios-6-1-adoption-on-track-to-be-fastest-yet-says-onswipe-with-22-of-users-on-board-in-36-hours/

And here's some info from Apple (dated Jan 28th 2013),

http://www.macrumors.com/2013/01/28/nearly-300-million-devices-running-ios-6-60-of-all-ios-devices-ever/

Comment: Yeah, I saw that article but it doesn't say anything about the percent of 5.0/5.1 users, which is what I'm interested in.

Comment: Also looked at Onswipe.com in hopes of a current source, but nothing there.

Comment: From the Apple data I added, I think it's safe to assume that the majority are now on 6, with a fair chunk still on 5.x.  iPhones, back to the 3GS, can support 6.1, and I'm seeing my user base rapidly move over, with a very small % of stragglers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's too late to answer the question but I found a link in Apple Support Center where they show a frugal statistics.

[image: iOS Adoption Statistics]

The link is here: https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/